# masked_scatter but rowwise?

Tags: python, pytorch

Assuming a mask as follows:

```
mask = torch.tensor([
  [True,  True,  False, True,  False],
  [True,  False, True,  True,  True ],
])
```

I would like to number the `True` values with sequential values in each row separately. I don't care what's in the `False` spots, so `0` for simplicity. Thus the desired result is

```
tensor([[0, 1, 0, 2, 0],    # 0 1 _ 2 _
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]])   # 0 _ 1 2 3
```

I hoped this would work:

```
replacements = torch.arange(mask.size(1)).expand(mask.size())
target = torch.zeros(mask.size(), dtype=int)
target.masked_scatter(mask, replacements)
```

Unfortunately, `masked_scatter` ignores the shape of `replacements`, so this code results in:

```
tensor([[0, 1, 0, 2, 0],    # 0 1 _ 2 _
        [3, 0, 4, 0, 1]])   # 3 _ 4 0 1
```

What would I need to do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something with [`torch.cumsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.cumsum.html): `torch.cumsum(mask,dim=1) -1) * mask`

The complete example

```py
import torch
mask = torch.tensor([
  [True,  True,  False, True,  False],
  [True,  False, True,  True,  True ],
])
result=torch.cumsum(mask,dim=1) -1) * mask
print(result)
```

That would print:

```
tensor([[0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Oh, that works great, thanks. I don't even need `* mask` (as I said, I don't care about the `False` slots :P )